# 'Int' is not a subtype of '()' Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

The below code throws the error ,'Int' is not a subtype of '()'

```
func addHelpFunction() -> (Int -> Int){
    func adderfunc() -> Int {
        return 6
    }
    return adderfunc
}
```

Now, if I parameterise the inner function it works fine

```
func addHelpFunction() -> (Int -> Int){
    func adderfunc(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }
    return adderfunc
}
```

after compiling the code , it throws a new error "failed with exit code 254"

Comment: Your second example works for me without error. How are you compiling it?

Comment: I have cleaned the code and build using Xcode

Comment: Have you tried it outside of the context of a project? Like just in a playground, for example? Or compiled from the commandline?

Comment: I had the code in AppDelegate.swift. But, if Use the same code in playground it works fine.

Comment: That second error looks like it's either a Swift bug or something else in your program is causing it. The first error is because the signature of the closure you were returning `(Void -> Int)` didn't match the function's return signature `(Int -> Int)`.

Comment: So, the return type of addHelpFunction is equivalent to (inner function parameter input type -> inner function return type)

Comment: That's right - you can read up on function types here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addHelpFunction()` function is returning a function typed as `(Int) -> (Int)`.  In your first example, you are returning `adderFunc()` that is typed as `() -> (Int)` and thus violates the required return type.  In your second example, `adderFunc()` is typed properly.

Note that a more idiomatic way to implement `addHelpFunction()` is to return an anonymous closure as:

```
func addHelpFunction() -> (Int -> Int) {
  return { (n:Int) -> (Int) in return 6 }
}
```

In action:

```
 41> var ret6 = addHelpFunction()
ret6: (Int -> Int) =
 42> ret6(10)
$R19: (Int) = 6
```

Perhaps using the idiomatic closure will avoid the possible compiler error.